# How can I use ftrace to get the in-kernel call graph called by a system call?

Tags: linux-kernel, ftrace

I've tried these, but all of them produce "empty" output files:

```
trace-cmd record -p function_graph -g munmap -F ls
trace-cmd record -p function_graph -g sys_enter_munmap -F ls
trace-cmd record -p function_graph -g sys_enter -F ls
```

Comment: Are you sure ftrace is enabled?

Comment: Yeah, it works if I just tell it to dump all events.

Comment: Well, I tried these and they work here (Ubuntu 2.6.35-28,trace-cmd version 1.0.3 ) so I would guess the problem lies in your specific kernel or ftrace-cmd version and/or config.

Comment: What command did you use to view the output? What kind of output did you get?

Comment: First I used vi to verify I have content in trace.dat. Then I used kernelshark to visualize the log.

Comment: That's odd, I would have thought that only one of the above commands would have worked.

Comment: hmm... seems something is fishy indeed. I tried now the command: 
" trace-cmd record -p function_graph -g xxx -F ls "

And it seems to produce the same output. I don't think the filtering works... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get the function name right - e.g. the function name to use for tracing `open` syscalls is `sys_open`.

To do this the "proper" way, it's necessary to have `function_graph` support in the kernel. On the x86 architecture [this depends on CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE being disabled](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695283), but on x86_64 it doesn't.

In my case I didn't bother to compile a custom kernel to disable CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE, I just did

```
trace-cmd record -p function --func-stack
```

and included various functions that looked like they might be called by adding several `-l` options. This was enough to figure out what I wanted to know.